# what is the first cohomology group of structure sheaf of grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I want to know if the first cohomology group of structure sheaf of grassmannian vanishes.

Comment: Hint:  the first cohomology group of the structure sheaf of a smooth projective variety is a birational invariant.

Comment: I suggest that you use MathStackExchange for your questions, which are not at research level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over the complex numbers, the Grassmanian $X = G(n,k)$ is simply-connected. Since this also a smooth projective variety, it is compact and Kaehler, so we have $0 =b_1(X) = 2h^{1,0}(X)$, where $b_1(X)$ denotes the first Betti number and $h^{1,0}(X) = \text{dim}\ H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)$. This gives the vanishing that you seek.